# Как можно изменить запускающий activity, после компилаци?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

У меня есть программа который пользователи регистрируется. На первом запуске откроется Activity для регистраций, но после регистраций каждый раз должен открываться Главный Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sText = preferences.getString("Loaded", "");

    if (sText.equals("yes")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecAct.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    adapter = new ShedsAdapter();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    api = ((App) getApplication()).getApi();
    api.getSheds("ПО", 1, 1).enqueue(new Callback<List<Shed>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Shed>> call, Response<List<Shed>> response) {
            Log.d("Tag", "onResponse");
            List<Shed> sheds = response.body();
            adapter.setSheds(sheds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Shed>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Tag", "onFailure", t);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}
`

Comment: Вам нужно сделать Splash в котором в зависимости от статуса регистрации будут вызываться соответствующие окна. [руководство по splash](https://habr.com/post/345380/)

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868897/Первый-запуск-приложения-авторизовать-пользователя-При-последующих-входах-пер/868909?noredirect=1#comment1407009_868909

Comment: У меня был похожий вопрос. Тут есть ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868897/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80/868959#868959. Думаю он вам подойдет.