# Первый запуск приложения, авторизовать пользователя. При последующих входах, перенаправлять пользователя на основную Activity( если он авторизован)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Приложение авторизовывает пользователя ( при первом входе ) через google, с помощью fireBase.

Первый запуск приложения, авторизовать пользователя. При последующих входах, перенаправлять пользователя на основную Activity(если он авторизован) не показывая activity с авторизацией.

SharedPreferences не подходит.

Прошу не кидаться камнями коллеги. Я только изучаю android и мне очень нужен совет более опытных товарищей. Спасибо

```
    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        binding.buttonGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            goMapScreen();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void goMapScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenMapActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Я аналогичную задачу решаю так:

1. Есть 2 активити `MainActivity`, который объявлен лончером в манифесте и `LoginActivity`, в котором производятся манипуляции входа
2. `LoginActivity` после авторизации куда-то пишет токен авторизации (в зависимости от того, что мы понимаем под авторизацией или в преференсы или в БД или в FireBase или даже в некоторых случаях просто как переменная в `MainActivity`
3. При запуске приложения в `MainActivity.onCreate()` проверяем факт авторизации (см. выше) если нет авторизации запускаем нечто типа `startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class))`
4. После успешной авторизации закрываем `LoginActivity.finish()` и запускаем еще раз `MainActivity` из `LoginActivity` через нечто похожее на: `startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class))`

Все.

Comment: можно просто диалог вывести: "Привет!! Давай авторизироваться" , полями логин-пароль и кнопкой "запишите и меня" :)

Comment: Ну с диалогом мороки много, я уже пробовал - чтобы диалог работал, нужен вызывающий его активити, а вызывающий активити надо как то инициализировать без авторизации, надо скрывать его или делать диалог на весь экран - в общем `Activity` как то сподручнее с ним.

Comment: @Barmaley Если возможно,пожалуйста опишите подробнее реализацию. 

Я сделал как вы сказали. Но у меня не выходит. Все равно первым запускается активити авторизации.

Кусок реализации в MainActivity ( Авторизация ) 

'irebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            finish();
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ScreenMapActivity.class));'

Comment: @Barmaley Так же я делаю проверку в классе, который нужно открывать первым для авторизованного пользователя ScreenMapActivity

' firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        } '

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать новый класс например `SplashScreenActivity.class`, который одновременно выполняет две функции показывает заставку и параллельно проверяет авторизацию. Для этого нужно переписать `AndroidManifest.xml`

Например:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

`SplashScreenActivity.class`

```
if (/* условие */) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
} else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Редактировал здесь, так что могут быть ошибки

Comment: Этот класс будет как дополнительный и будет выполнять только проверку?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=splash%20screen%20android&lr=213

Answer (score 0):

Если не подходит SharedPreferences, вы можете хранить их во внутренней папке приложения. 
File dir = new File(Environment.getCacheDirectory());

File stotage = new File(dir, "KEY_STORAGE");

Напишите в комментариях, если не понятно, как записывать и получать данные из файла.

Но сразу, мне удобнее это делать из:
BufferedReader